# Accepted answer changed to add the information from my own answer

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

I recently came across a question on Stack Overflow which was already answered and accepted, but the answer was wrong or at least highly incomplete and too complex. I then decided to write a new answer, which received quite a few upvotes immediately. One day after that, the author of the accepted answer just added the information from my answer to his own, rendering my answer completely useless now.

My problem is that now it appears that I just posted information which was already present in the accepted answer. (I mean, no one really checks the timestamps and edits, right?)

What is the Stack Overflow etiquette for something like this? I understand that it is most useful for anyone stumbling across this in the future, but I don't want to receive a bunch of downvotes in the future.

To avoid misunderstandings, I must emphasize once more that the author of the accepted answer did nothing wrong. He just improved his answer based on mine, which made me look like I have copy/pasted the essence of his answer. **This** bothers me it looks exactly like that when you don't check the timestamps.

I also don't want credit for it since the answer can be found on google if you take your time. I just didn't had no source because I stumbled upon this problem a while ago but still remembered the fix.

Comment: Crafty. I've seen this myself a few times. There's probably nothing you can do. Also see people make comments and then others use those comments as answers to gain the rep. Most do tag in the user to say where they got the idea/information from. As it happens, I check timestamps and edits. As an example I could quite easily now say `"Let it go" would be my advice....it happens`. And @Paulie_D now looks to have copied me ;)

Comment: "Let it go" would be my advice....it happens.

Comment: Hmm okay I understand. Lets hope that others will see the timestamps then. Since I have quite a few rep it kind of bothers me, since I don't want to loose the privileges. (I actually use them a lot for example to format/prettify answers, making them more readable). Thank you for your quick help :)

Comment: I don't understand why you are concerned about downvotes. Why would your answer get downvotes?

Comment: Like I already explained in the OP... If people don't pay attention to the timestamps, they could assume that I just plagiarized the information from his answer. I would downvote then, wouldn't you?

Comment: Well, no. I'd flag it for moderator attention with a custom flag pointing out the plagiarism. And obviously I would check the timestamps before doing anything, even if I were going to downvote. My point is, you should wait and see if there is a real problem. Do you *actually* receive a bunch of downvotes? I'm guessing no. What the person whose answer was accepted did might seem a bit sleazy, but it's actually for the good of the community, especially if the person who originally asked the question isn't an active user anymore and/or won't change the accepted mark to your answer.

Comment: Hmm did not think about flags, you are right, I understand your point. I did not receive any downvotes, I just assumed that this would inevitably happen in the future, because I would have done so (flagging is of course more suitable for a situation like that). Thanks for your help. Of course I understand that it is actually good that the author of the accepted answer edited his own, I already said so.

Comment: Oh! I just realized that what they *should* have done is given you credit, by linking to your answer. If they *didn't* do that, then SO etiquette would demand that someone edit the attribution into their answer. I can see why you wouldn't want to do it yourself, but if you posted the question here on Meta, I'm sure someone would be happy to oblige!

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I should have pointed that out better. Well, I also don't want to grab for attention or anything like that, I just wanted to know how to avoid misunderstandings. However, [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054821/shadow-piercing-inside-scss) a link to the question. Thanks again for all the help :)

Comment: First I apologize to Christian Dreher. I agree that this doesn't make me look too good and might not be the best behavior. A few notes. When I made this edit I assumed that a space still has the same behavior as `>>>` and `/deep/`. I follow the Angular2 changes quite closely and was sure that I had noticed such a change. To me it seemed like an attempt to hijack a question without much value where I already had my answer accepted, which happens a lot. 
It depends on whether I can affort the time to do deeper checks. Often I do this time I obviously didn't.

Comment: You can see in this discussion https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8936#issuecomment-223403762 that I knew this specific bit of information long before and I also mentioned it in several other answers months before Christians answer. I generally don't steal information from other answers and add it to mine when I didn't know that before myself without credit. I also learned from discussions on meta that it is good or at least accepted practice to improve ones answer with information even when it is already included in other answers.

Comment: One more point " received quite a few upvotes immediately." The answer has 2 upvotes. One is from me.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thank you very much for joining this discussion. I never wanted to allege bad behaviour to you, I was rather unsure on how to deal with such a situation. I have to apologize if I made it look like that. Obviously I don't know that much about this specific problem (regarding to angular2), but at least I thought I have found a way to fix this specific issue. Sorry if I did not research further, I rather wanted to give quick advise since it worked for me. And to the upvotes: I did not check the number before saying this, but obviously I exaggerated.

Comment: So thank you for resolving this, it is really good to know your point of view. And thanks to all who contributed to solve this, I will know better in the future :)

Comment: @ChristianDreher thanks for starting the discussion instead of just maintaining a grudge ;-)

Comment: I never had one, sorry if it looked that way, I just didn't want to look like copy/pasting others answers and didn't know how i should deal with it. I already emphasized that I know why what you did is important and in the interests of the community. And eventually, that's all that counts.

Comment: We need a report option for that I think

Comment: No, definitely not. Günter did nothing wrong, his answer was already accepted and he did not stole anything, he just improved his answer based on mine. I have no problem with this, as he seems to be a valuable community member. I just did not want to look like I have plagiarized from him, because without checking the timestamps it certainly looks like that